# AngularJS: smart-table dynamically change the table contents as per http response from server

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have created a table using smart table. Now I want each event like sort and filter to send an http request to the server and refresh the table contents based on the response. For example, if I click sort on a columns (say `id` column) I want it to trigger an http request to the server with `?sort=id` or some other custom http request with logic defined in my controller. How can I achieve this ? I could see that I can use an array as `stSafeSrc` and when it's contents change dynamically, the table will reload itself. So, the idea is to keep changing the contents of the array using http responses from the server. However, I am not sure how can I trigger custom http requests to server based on the action performed on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use web-sockets
2. Use $interval, sent $http to server (server return last id row in table, if lastId not equal lastId in your table, you need $rootScope.$emit('triggerEmit'))
   //before $inject = '$rootScoope'

Good luck!

```
//directive
   $rootScope.$$listeners.triggerTableXYZ = [];
   $rootScope.$on('triggerTableXYZ ', function (event, data) {});
   //controller
   $rootScope.$emit('triggerTableXYZ ', response.data);
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't able to explain my requirement clearly. Actually what I was trying to accomplish could be done by overriding the `stPipe` function of the smart table library. Thanks anyways

Comment: @mandeep_m91  Could you please post that as an answer, to help future searchers? After two days, the system will let you accept your own answer. That is helpful behaviour. Also helpful would be a short code sample of the answer ;-)